# Loading module was blocked because of a disallowed MIME type (“application/wasm”)

Tags: javascript, rust, webassembly, wasm-pack, x-content-type-options

I serve a static file server (through HTTP), which contains data generated by `wasm-pack`. Using the examples from the rustwasm book, I added this code to my index HTML page:

```
        <script type="module">
            import init from "./pkg/fstree_web.js";

            async function run() {
                await init();
            }

            run();
        </script>
```

However, on Firefox, I get the error message as indicated in the title:

> module from “http://localhost:8000/pkg/fstree_web_bg.wasm” was blocked because of a disallowed MIME type (“application/wasm”).

I suspected HTTPS issues or localhost issues, so I additionally tried `127.0.0.1`, and even tried an https://***.ngrok.io tunnel, and Firefox still rejects loading the wasm module with this error message.

It links to an MDN article about X-Content-Type-Options, but I am not sure how it is relevant. My server is already sending `Content-Type: application/wasm`.

The JavaScript code generated by wasm-pack starts with this:

```
import { __cargo_web_snippet_72fc447820458c720c68d0d8e078ede631edd723 } from './snippets/stdweb-bb142200b065bd55/inline133.js';
import { __cargo_web_snippet_97495987af1720d8a9a923fa4683a7b683e3acd6 } from './snippets/stdweb-bb142200b065bd55/inline134.js';
import { __cargo_web_snippet_dc2fd915bd92f9e9c6a3bd15174f1414eee3dbaf } from './snippets/stdweb-bb142200b065bd55/inline135.js';
import { __cargo_web_snippet_1c30acb32a1994a07c75e804ae9855b43f191d63 } from './snippets/stdweb-bb142200b065bd55/inline136.js';
import { wasm_bindgen_initialize } from './snippets/stdweb-bb142200b065bd55/inline293.js';
import * as wasm from './fstree_web_bg.wasm';
```

Does Firefox want me to send *.wasm as a `application/javascript`? Or what is wrong?

Comment: Hey, if you post the previous link in a comment, I can tell you if there was an answer there or not.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58311656/x-wasm-was-blocked-because-of-a-disallowed-mime-type-application-wasm

Comment: Yeah, no one answered it. It was posted Oct 9 and deleted yesterday without a comment or answer.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The importing of WebAssembly modules is not yet standardized. You should set the `--target` argument of wasm-pack to `web` to generate JavaScript to use in a browser.

Comment: I already did, but it generated the JavaScript above. The libraries I'm using, like stdweb, use snippets. Could that be related?

Comment: Is this an extension by any chance or a normal web page?

Comment: Doubt. I reproduce the same issue on chrome without any extensions

Comment: I was asking if you are developing an extension, but then I assume you are not.

Comment: Try to replace the wasm import line with direct instantiation of the module (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/WebAssembly/Loading_and_running).

Comment: I'll try. Should I consider this a bug for wasm-pack?

Comment: Oh never mind, I made a typo in my toolchain that made it unable to pass `--target web` to wasm-pack. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if you have/had the same problem as me (trying to do the tutorial without using js-bundler), but I finally got it to work on my end.

Trying to attempt to get a handle on the `*.wasm` file you generated is already taken care of by the `--target web` parameter, so you don't actually need to import your `*_bg.wasm` file, but since the `wasm` Object (I'm not too sure yet, what this is) is actually returned by the `init()` function.

So if you want to carry on using the `wasm` handle, just do:

```js
// Near imports worked for me, but choose your own scope
let wasm;
.
.
.
// instead of await init();
wasm = await init();
```